# How to extract property names from custom class in C#

Tags: c#, csv, properties, export, extract

I am making function for exporting table to .csv file.

I have List where T is custom class.

I need property names of T for columns in .csv file.

How can I extract them to other List ?

Comment: You can use `Type.GetProperties` to get all properties then `MemberInfo.Name` to get name for each. But the csv-serialization looks like a pretty standard task, so it may be good idea to use one of existing libraries to solve this.

Comment: Unless it is some kind of exercise - try looking into existing libraries like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties()
      .Select(p => p.Name));
```

Comment: Better to use `item.GetType()` for each element of the collection instead of `typeof(T)`, as the collection may also contains items, which are not exactly of type `T`, but of some type, derived from `T`. And such a derived type may have some additional properties.

Comment: Of course this solution doesn't work for every possible scenario, but the OP didn't post any code or further requirements, just stated that "I need property names of T", I am not sure about the deeper business requirements his application has, I just answered the question he asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a tad hard to understand.
However I wrote some example code for you, hopefully it answers your question.
As I believe you just needed help with the reflection part of the question.

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace Example
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var props = GetProperties(type);

                foreach (var property in props)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Type: {type.FullName} -> Property: {property.Name}");
                }
            }
        }

        public static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(Type T)
        {
            return T.GetProperties();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Health { get; set; } // Example property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I maintain some libraries that make this very easy: [Sylvan.Data.Csv and Sylvan.Data](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan).

The Sylvan.Data library provides an API for turning an `IEnumerable<T>` into a `DbDataReader` (`AsDataReader`). The Sylvan.Data.Csv library provides an API for writing `DbDataReader` to a CSV file (`CsvDataWriter`). You can combine these to make an extension method:

```
using Sylvan.Data;
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;

static class CsvMethods
{
    public static long WriteAsCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, string file)
        where T : class
    {
        using var writer = File.CreateText(file);
        return WriteAsCsv(seq, writer);
    }

    public static long WriteAsCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, TextWriter output) 
        where T : class
    {
        using var csvWriter = CsvDataWriter.Create(output);
        return csvWriter.Write(seq.AsDataReader());
    }
}
```

You can then write your `List<T>` to a CSV file with one line of code:

```
List<MyData> data = ...;
data.WriteAsCsv("mydata.csv");
```

The code implementing these libraries is extremely efficient, and will handle CSV edge-cases like fields containing delimiters, quotes, etc.